# increase size of image without increasing resolution

Tags: images, resolution

I want a  image with resolution 150 pixels (Width) X 200 pixels (Height) and file size should be in between 15 KB and 30 KB. (this is for applying in an online exam)
I cropped the image into the required resolution, but its size was 12.9 KB.

What should i do to make the size above 15 KB without increasing resolution.

Thanks and regards

Comment: Are you sure it needs to be a minimum of 15K (vs. 15-30K being a general not-to-exceed guideline)?  What is the image format/filetype (is any compression involved)?  What is the nature/subject of the image (photo, line art, screenshot of text, vector image)?

Comment: If it is a jpeg you could add EXIF or XMP metadata.  Add some character say X in multiple times in multiple fields.

Answer (score 0):

That means that the quality is probably not good enough. You can sprinkle some noise into it with respective tools, but that just blows up the size, and the quality gets worse. You should rather try to get a higher quality picture to start with.

Also, check the cropping process you used; redo it and when you save into JPG after cropping, you can change the options, set it to 'max quality' there (the default is often set to 25% or so, which reduces size and quality).

Answer (score 0):

If both height and width must not change, you got several options:

1. Increase compression quality (simply open and save the file)
2. add Metadata (on Windows you can right-click, properties, Details-Tab. Then enter some lengthy text at Title, Comments or Subject)